# canvas js graph with double values doesn't appear on page

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, canvasjs

I use visual studio and c#.
So I am trying to plot a graph with using of canvas.js. 
My code is:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@{
    double[] a = { 2.2, 2 };
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function () {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                theme: "theme2",                          
                axisY: {
                    title: "Logarithmic Axis",
                    logarithmic: true,                   
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        type: "line", 
                        dataPoints: [{ y: @a[0]},
                                     { y: @a[1]}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });
            chart.render();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If array a consists of only integers it works. However, when a has doubles the graph doesn't appear on page. How to fix it?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Comment: Works fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqzh7vtp/)

Comment: @kemotoe I need to set the array a not in script but in @{ }